# Regedit file format

Tags: windows, registry, regedit

I would like to document the file format of regedit utility, so data can be merged into the registry.

From the command-line you can (silently) merge data from a batch file like this:

```
regedit /s file.reg
```

Exporting from a subkey goes like this:

```
regedit /e file.reg "HKEY_XX\key"
```

Comment: I don't think SO's intention is to rebuild all the knowledge of the internet in one place, but rather to fill the gaps a Google search leaves open.

Comment: On the other hand, rebuilding all the world's knowledge IS [Wikipedia's mission](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry#.REG_files)   (found, as @Tomalak hinted, by the same Google search that led to this question)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Remove keys and values by using the minus sign (-).

```
REGEDIT4
[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\RemoveThisTree]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\RemoveValue]
"valueName"=-
```

#### References

- Minus sign to delete mentioned here: [MSKB310516: *How to add, modify, or delete registry subkeys and values by using a .reg file*](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310516) (Archived [here](https://archive.is/PECXd).)
- Minus sign to delete, semicolon to comment and IF/ENDIF mentioned here: [MSDN: *Registry File (Compact 2013)*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg469889.aspx) (Archived [here](https://archive.is/n4sj6).)

Comment: Cool, I didn't know the minus sign removed registry keys and values. Good info.

Comment: IF ENDIF is neither used by `reg` command nor `regedit`. It is about `Platform Builder for Windows Embedded Compact 2013.

Answer (score 15):

Documenting the .reg file format is really more [Microsoft's job](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310516).

Comment: Although that documentation is not entirely. Go Microsoft.